# How to disable Proguard settings for an external dependency jar?

Tags: gradle, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

My project consists of 2 modules - an application and a library. The library, in turn, includes (via "Compile") another jar (whose classes are referenced directly in the application as well).

Questions:

1. How should I configure Proguard to run on the app, on the library but NOT on the included jar?
2. Should I put any proguard settings in build.gradle for the library?
3. Should I put anything with respect to the jar in build.gradle for the app?

Currently, this is what I have in the app:

```
    buildTypes {
      release {
        debuggable false
        zipAlign true
        runProguard true
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not possible at the moment to exclude a dependency when running ProGuard.
2. You should only proguard the library if you want to obfuscate parts of it. This is only really useful if you want to only offer part of it as a public API. You definitively do not want to remove dead code, since you don't know what will get used or not.
3. On the app side, you probably don't need to put anything special, unless the library code requires you to not obfuscate some specific class. If that's the case you should actually publish this from the library so that the app uses that automatically. There's a sample called `libProguardConsumerFiles` that shows how to do this using the `consumerProguardFiles` properties. This will include a proguard rule file in the library packaging that will get used by whomever consumes the library.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. I updated the questions. Can you please check again? Also, does proguard-android-optimize include proguard-android?